# Python Pandas: check if items from list is in df index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
    'team': ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Packers', 'Packers', 'Lions', 'Lions', 'Lions'],
    'wins': ['11102', '8425', '12%', '15%', '11%', '6%', '20%', '4%'],
    'losses': ['5222', '8888', '6%', '1%', '5%', '30%', '6%', '12%'],
    }
football = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','ssa'], columns=['year', 'team', 'wins', 'losses'])
```

I also have a list:

```
fixed_cats = ['d','g','ssa']
```

I would like to check if the items from the fixed_cats list are found at the bottom of the df's index.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
football.loc[football.index[-len(fixed_cats):].isin(fixed_cats)]
```

for some reason, this returns a df with the index ['b','c'].

Expected output:

a df with the index of 'g' and 'ssa'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you saw `['b','c']` in your first attempt is that what is returned from the inner `isin` is a boolean index of `[False, True, True]` which you're applying to the df from the beginning, you need to reapply it again to the last 3 rows:

```
In [21]:

fixed_cats = ['d','g','ssa']
football[-len(fixed_cats):][football.index[-len(fixed_cats):].isin(fixed_cats)]
Out[21]:
     year   team wins losses
g    2011  Lions  20%     6%
ssa  2012  Lions   4%    12%

In [22]:

football.index[-len(fixed_cats):].isin(fixed_cats)
Out[22]:
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

So the above boolean index needs to be applied to the last 3 rows rather to the entire df again which is what you are doing

Comment: Thanks Ed. That's exactly what I wanted to do. I'll try and remember this for the future!