# Python Pandas: check if items from list is in df index where df is a multiindex df

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe:

```
                       colname        ... TemporaryFix
ID1   ID2    ID3                              
a      NA    1         New Sector  ...             
b      NA    20        Market Sector  ...             
c      NA    5         Market Sector  ...             
d      NA    5         Other Sector  ...             
e      a27   55        Market Sector  ...
```

I have a column name and corresponding list of indices.

```
cname = 'Market Sector'
lindex = [('b', NA, 20), ('d', NA, 5)
```

I want to enter 'yes' in column 'TemporaryFix' where the indices are in the list and colname equals cname.

```
Desired output:
                       colname        ... TemporaryFix
ID1   ID2    ID3                               
a      NA    1         New Sector  ...             
b      NA    20        Market Sector  ... yes            
c      NA    5         Market Sector  ...             
d      NA    5         Other Sector  ...             
e      a27   55        Market Sector  ...
```

wrote the following (adapting solution in [Python Pandas: check if items from list is in df index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023384/python-pandas-check-if-items-from-list-is-in-df-index)):

```
df['TemporaryFix'] = np.where((df[(df.index.isin(lindex)) & (df['colname'] == cname)]),'yes','')
```

it didn't work. Have I made a mistake in my code or is it because it's a mulitindex df? Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cname = 'Market Sector'
lindex = [('b', pd.NA, 20), ('d', pd.NA, 5)]
```

Try:

via boolean masking and `.loc` accessor

```
m=(df['colname'].eq(cname)) & (df.index.isin(lindex))
df.loc[m,'TemporaryFix']='yes'
```

OR

via `np.where()`:

```
m=(df['colname'].eq(cname)) & (df.index.isin(lindex))
df['TemporaryFix']=np.where(m,'yes','')
```

Comment: thanks this worked. Based on your answer I revised my code to ```df['TemporaryFix'] = np.where(((df['colname'] == (cname)) & (df.index.isin(lindex))), 'yes', '')```. That worked too. The extra df after np.where was incorrect.